# Парсинг JSON строки

Tags: c#, json, строки, double

Есть json и я его обрабатываю

```
{"success":true,"message":"","result":[{"price":0.07205551]}
```

вот так

```
dynamic exchange = JObject.Parse(response);
JArray answerjsonall = (JArray)exchange["result"];
return exchange["result"][0]["price"].ToString();
```

На выход уходит 0,07205551   (с запятой)
Почему так и как исправить?

Comment: А какого результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: что бы оно вывело с точкой, и  без такого 2,6E-07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что числа преобразуются в строку в формате вашего текущего языка.

Либо поменяйте текущий язык вашего потока (`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");`, либо преобразовывайте в строку с указанием языка (`.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`).

Если хотите управлять выводом вашего числа более подробно, почитайте документацию о форматных строках:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что настройки локали влияют на формат вывод чисел (также дат, времени, дней недели и т.д.)